# Can Twilio be used to build a webinar platform with desktop sharing?

Tags: twilio, webinar

Would like to build a webinar product that can do live presenter video, desktop sharing, slide presentation. Does Twilio have the platform to provide the backend resources to make this happen?

Comment: twilio can do the voice part, but twilio doesn't do video

Comment: or desktop sharing or slide presentation..

Comment: Twilio does do Video (https://www.twilio.com/video) for browser, iOS and Android applications, but no screen sharing at the moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could build audio and video streaming using Twilio's [video capabilities](https://www.twilio.com/video). This infrastructure however is not built for streaming for large audiences as of the time of writing.

So to answer your question, you could build a platform where you can record and share your videos, but live streamming would be limited.

Think of Twilio's streaming capabilities as something more like Skype or Google Hangouts rather than Twitch.

Have a look at our [Video Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video) to find out more about Twilio's video capabilities.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! Are you aware of a development platform that would provide for high-volume webinars (1,000 participants)?

Comment: Does Twilio have a product where one can share his screen (like Paint drawing) to a peer's browser?